# How to use vtk in Cutsom C++ Project using CLion/CMake and Win10

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, vtk, cmakelists-options

somehow I can’t get vtk to properly run in my project.
I have downloaded, build and installed vtk-9.3 on my local machine.
I can also find the VTK Packages and it’s modules, as well as reference the Header-Files.
For the Unit-Tests I’m using Googletest.
When calling my Unit-Tests some Linker-Errors occure
Also when i try to execute the .exe file I receive some missing dll errors (vtksys-9.3.dll etc.)

Implementation:

```
set(VTK_DIR "${CPP_LIBS_DIR}/vtk")
set(VTK_LIBRARIES "${VTK_DIR}/lib")
include_directories("${VTK_LIBRARIES}/vtk/lib")
...
find_package(VTK
        COMPONENTS REQUIRED
        CommonCore
        ImagingCore
        RenderingCore
        RenderingVolume
        RenderingOpenGL2
        RenderingVolumeOpenGL2
        IOLegacy
        FiltersCore
        vtksys)
...

target_link_libraries(aws_3d_nesting PRIVATE ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
vtk_module_autoinit(
        TARGETS aws_3d_nesting
        MODULES VTK::CommonCore VTK::ImagingCore VTK::RenderingCore VTK::RenderingVolume VTK::RenderingOpenGL2 VTK::RenderingVolumeOpenGL2 VTK::IOLegacy VTK::FiltersCore VTK::vtksys
)
```

Only when calling my Unit-Tests some Linker-Errors occure:

```
UnitTests.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl vtkDebugLeaksManager::vtkDebugLeaksManager(void)" (__imp_??0vtkDebugLeaksManager@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'vtkDebugLeaksManagerInstance''(void)" (??__EvtkDebugLeaksManagerInstance@@YAXXZ)".

UnitTests.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl vtkDebugLeaksManager::~vtkDebugLeaksManager(void)" (__imp_??1vtkDebugLeaksManager@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'vtkDebugLeaksManagerInstance''(void)" (??__FvtkDebugLeaksManagerInstance@@YAXXZ)".

UnitTests.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup::vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup(void)" (__imp_??0vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanupInstance''(void)" (??__EvtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanupInstance@@YAXXZ)".

UnitTests.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup::~vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup(void)" (__imp_??1vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanupInstance''(void)" (??__FvtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanupInstance@@YAXXZ)".

unitTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

In my solution build folder there are also no DLL’s present.
I can’t find the issue that is causing this problems.
Has anybody an idea what might be the root of this?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: ***In my solution build folder there are also no DLL’s present.*** Why are there no vtk dlls? Remember that extra steps need to occur if you try to statically link vtk because of the object registration in the vtkObjectFactory

Comment: ***I receive some missing dll errors***  Provided the dlls exist those should be fixed by telling your OS where the dlls are so it can find them. There are 2 very easy methods. One involves putting the dlls into the same folder as your executable. The other common easy method is to add the folder containing these dlls to the OS PATH environment variable.

Comment: This Microsoft document explains how your OS searches for dependent dlls and what you need to do to help the search be successful: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps)